# Add value in input form Laravel 5.5

Tags: forms, laravel-5

How to add an extra value while adding data in input form `laravel 5.5`?

For example the extra value is 123 and I want to place it before input like
"123+input" .
So if we input "john", it will appear "123john" into the database.

I have used the following code:

```html
{!! Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name', 'value' => '123'.'name' )) !!}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: do you want to add a specific value every time or different values every time?

Comment: i prefer to use specific value every time

Comment: ok, then you can do it in controller.
See my answer i will post it in a few minutes.

Comment: ok Sir thank you for your help

Comment: See my answer i have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller
You can concatenate the desired value before `name` like this:

```
$name = "123".$request['name'];
```

As I saw your comment in @Haider Ali's answer here's what you need:

```
 public function store(Request $request){ 
     $request['name'] = "123".$request['name'];
     Guest::create($request->all()); 
     return redirect('guest'); 
 }
```

Comment: yes Sir, it works now. thank you very much for your help. regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your value with the form request input in controller like this:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $name = "123".$request->name;
    Guest::create([
       'name' => $name,
       //'otherfield' => $request->other
    ]); 
   return redirect('guest'); 
}
```

And then you can save it in database if you like.

Or you can put the default text as value for the input and one can add their own value to that in addition to that default. And in jquery you can restrict the user to not remove the default value from input.

```
{!! Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name', 'value' => '123' )) !!}
```

Comment: this is my controller .
public function store(Request $request){
   Guest::create($request->all());
   return redirect('guest');
}
how to add it Sir?

Comment: OK let me rewrite answer for you!

Comment: As I don't know what other fields do you have, so i have just put the name in creating guest, you can put your other request objects in the array like the commented one

Comment: ok Sir, it works! thank you very much for your help. regards.